# Error copying database using a preloaded database for sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Please i am trying to create a login from a preloaded database. But i am having problems copying database. Below is my debug error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.babbangona.preloadedtestingagain, PID: 11863
>                     java.lang.Error: Error copying database
>                         at com.babbangona.preloadedtestingagain.DBHandler.createDatabase(DBHandler.java:42)
>                         at com.babbangona.preloadedtestingagain.DBcopyActivity$1.onClick(DBcopyActivity.java:28)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6199)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23235)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1073)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934) I/art:
>   Enter while loop. I/art: Enter while loop. Disconnected from the
>   target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'

**My DBHandler java file:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    String DB_PATH = null;
    private static String DB_NAME = "rehoboth.db";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
    private final Context myContext;

    public DBHandler(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 2);
        this.myContext = context;
        this.DB_PATH = "/data/data" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        Log.e("Path 1", DB_PATH);
    }

    public void createDatabase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();
        if(dbExist){
           /* openDatabase();
            int cVersion = myDatabase.getVersion();
            if(cVersion != 2){
                onUpgrade(myDatabase, myDatabase.getVersion(),2);
                close();
            }*/
        }else{
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try{
                copyDatabase();
            }catch (IOException e){
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDatabase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }catch(SQLiteException e){
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }


    private void copyDatabase() throws IOException{
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
        int length;
        while((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDatabase() throws SQLException{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close(){
        if(myDatabase != null)
            myDatabase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
       if(newVersion > oldVersion)
           try{
               copyDatabase();
           }catch (IOException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
    }

    public Cursor query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy){
        return myDatabase.query("rehoboth", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

**My main Activity:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

public class DBcopyActivity extends Activity {

    Cursor c = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dbcopy);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                DBHandler myDbHelper = new DBHandler(DBcopyActivity.this);
                try{
                    myDbHelper.createDatabase();
                }catch(IOException ioe){
                    throw new Error("Unable to create database");
                }try{
                    myDbHelper.openDatabase();
                }catch(SQLException sqle){
                    throw sqle;
                }
                Toast.makeText(DBcopyActivity.this, "Successfully Imported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                c = myDbHelper.query("rehoboth", null, null, null, null, null, null);
                if(c.moveToFirst()){
                    do{
                        Toast.makeText(DBcopyActivity.this,
                                "_id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
                                "NAME: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                                        "PASSWORD: " + c.getString(2),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }while (c.moveToNext());
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/).

Comment: Okay thanks to those who didnt reply. I used the SQLiteAssetHelper, take note to ensure that you get the syntax ad Upper or Lower cases right. My porblem was during the creation of the "databases" folder in the asset folder, i named it as "Databases" instead of "databases". Apparently they don't tell that in tutorials